# How to set LINKMAP property

Tags: orientdb

This is how I am trying to set the LINKMAP property and it is not working. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
public static void setOrientLinkMapProperty(OVertex srcVertex, String propName, String linkMapKey, OVertex newPropVertex) {
        Map<String, ORID> currLinkMap = srcVertex.getProperty(propName);

        if (currLinkMap == null) currLinkMap = new HashMap<>();

        srcVertex.setProperty(propName, currLinkMap.put(linkMapKey, newPropVertex.getIdentity()), OType.LINKMAP);
        srcVertex.save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure SQL way of setting the `LINKMAP` is as follows:

```sql
CREATE CLASS Example EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY Example.name STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Example.map LINKMAP

CREATE VERTEX Example SET name = 'a'
CREATE VERTEX Example SET name = 'b'

UPDATE (SELECT FROM Example WHERE name = 'a') SET map = {'b':(SELECT FROM Example WHERE name = 'b')}
```

I'm not sure why your code is not working, it seems correct.

Perhaps try explicitly initializing the `HashMap`:

```java
currLinkMap = new HashMap<String, ORID>(); // Explicitly initialized hashmap
currLinkMap.put(linkMapKey, newPropVertex.getIdentity());
srcVertex.setProperty(propName, currLinkMap, OType.LINKMAP);
srcVertex.save();
```

Do you have any errors when running that code?